# I am trying to make a triangle area calculator with a gui but I keep getting this odd error when I compile it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class FirstGui extends JFrame {

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    //Buttons 'n' stuff
    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JRadioButton button;
    private JButton calculate;
    private JTextField textfield1;
    private JTextField textfield2;
    //Buttons 'n' stuff

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        FirstGui gui = new FirstGui();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(200, 200);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("T Calc");
    }

    public FirstGui(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label1 = new JLabel ("Triangle Base");
        add(label1);

        textfield1 = new JTextField (15);
        add(textfield1);

        label2 = new JLabel ("Triangle Height");
        add(label2);

        textfield2 = new JTextField (15);
        add(textfield2);

        calculate = new JButton ("Calculate!");
        add(calculate);

        label3 = new JLabel ("Waiting for calculation...");
        add(label3);


        getvalue1 getvalue1 = new getvalue1();
        textfield1.addActionListener(getvalue1);

        getvalue2 getvalue2 = new getvalue2();
        textfield2.addActionListener(getvalue2);

        event event = new event();
        button.addActionListener(event);
    }


    public class getvalue1 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent getvalue1){
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText());

        }
    }

    public class getvalue2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent getvalue2){
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText());

        }
    }
    public class event implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            num3 = 1/2 *num1*num2;
            label3.setText(String.valueOf(num3));
        }

    }

}
```

So yeah, that's the code ..
here is the problem I get when I compile it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FirstGui.<init>(FirstGui.java:56)
    at FirstGui.main(FirstGui.java:20)
```

I just have no clue what is wrong..
it's really annoying and I am not sure whether it's the compiler or not... help!!!
The error is not really very helpful.

Comment: Learn how to read stack traces. The error is pretty specific - you are trying to dereference NULL value on **line 56**, which is somewhere in `FirstGui` constructor (`<init>` method).

Comment: You're not getting that error when you COMPILE your code - you're getting the error when you RUN it.  It's harder to get good answers out of Stack Overflow when you misreport the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialised `button` anywhere in your code. You need to do this before attempting to invoke any methods on it.

```
button = new JRadioButton("Your text here");
```

More importantly, I can't see any other place where you're using that component. You haven't added it to your frame. Did you mean to add event that to the calculate button?